# Different results in Evernote search and API search

Tags: evernote, reminders

I would like to search for all notes with reminder_time today. I use the following search query for this purpose:

```
reminderTime:day -reminderTime:day+1
```

If I use it in the Evernote client everything works fine. But if I use the findNotesMetadata function in the word field in the NoteFilter parameter I also get notes with reminder tomorrow. The official API documentation says for the word field in the NoteFilter-struct:

> If present, a search query string that will filter the set of notes to be returned. Accepts the full search grammar documented in the Evernote API Overview.

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify - you're trying to get notes which have reminders set for within the next day? And you're getting the notes you expect on the (mac/windows) client but you're not getting the same notes back using the API?

Comment: I want to get all notes with reminder today. If I use the search in the windows/mac client I get exactly the notes I expected. If I try the search via API I got notes with reminder tomorrow too. So the search results doesn't match.

Comment: Do me a favour and try it on the web client? The web client calls findNotesMetadata directly so you _should_ get the same results as using the API

Comment: Thank you for this tip. OK the webclient produces the same wrong results. If I search for "notebook:MyNotebook" it returns results from all notebooks. But it should return only notes from the notebook MyNotebook.

Comment: try adding doublequotes, i.e. notebook:"MyNotebook". Shouldn't be needed if your notebook name is one word, but needed if your notebook name has multiple words

Comment: Yes I know. But with or without it produces the same results. But I could isolate the problem a little bit. In private notes the search for notebooks works, but in the business account I get all notes. So the problem focuses only business accounts.

Comment: Good catch with the "notebook:" filter on EB accounts - we have open ticket where we never added support for the "notebook:" filter. As far as I can tell, though, all other ones should work.
One of the problems we may be seeing with reminders is a time zone difference - you may be seeing reminders for the next 24 hours, instead of "tomorrow" as a user would think about it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Do you plan to implement this filter or do I need to build a work around?

Comment: Yes, the code to fix it has been merged in, will go out with this week's release. Usually Wednesday evening, sometimes Thursday.

Comment: Thank you. Now, it perfectly works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the notebook filter wasn't working correctly for business accounts. This was caused by a bug (slash not-implemented feature) in the Evernote service where the `notebook:"notebookName"` feature wasn't implemented in the Evernote service. It has now been implemented, and everything works perfectly.

Comment: Unfortunally, I have an issue with the implementation. If there are two notebooks in the business with the same name, but created and associated to different users, e.g. User a has a private "INBOX" notebook and user b, too, a search for "notebook:INBOX" return not the correct notes. I can found this in the API and the web view.

Comment: You should be able to use the notebookGuid field of the search filter instead of passing the notebook name to the filter's words

Answer (score 0):

There is still a difference in the API and the Evernote view. I want to search all notes created today. As the API documentation says the query is:

```
created:day
```

From the API I get all notes created from today 9:00 until tomorrow 8:59 (tomorrow date is manually changed in the note meta data). So I get the time interval from today for PST time zone, but I'm in Europe/Berlin, which explains a time difference of 9 hours between my location and Evernotes headquarter.

If I run the same query in Evernote Mac Client or the Evernote web client I get the correct notes from today in my time zone. In the Evernote Account, the correct time zone is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Using the API, the concept of "days" will use UTC when searching for notes - we don't take the User.timezone field into account. When you use a client eg the web or mac client, the current time zone will be taken from the system when interpreting a search query.

Comment: Why is the User.timezone field not be used. If your clients only take care of the system timezone, why users have to specify this in there accounts?

Comment: Nevertheless, its not using UTC. It's using UTC-7 for the calculation. Earlier you wrote the API should produce the same results as the web view. Is there a possibility to provide the user timezone to the api call, so I can reproduce the same results?

Comment: The user timezone is used when sending a "reminder email" for when users set reminders for particular days. I can't think of other places we actually use it. Clients don't use it since 1. the user's "current" timezone isn't necessarily the same as the configured one, and 2. the configured timezone is a relatively new field, we added it around the time we added reminders. 2014 maybe?

Comment: Yeah it might be using UTC-7 - we made a bad decision early on to have our servers set to Pacific time and so persistent storage  that uses "datetime" instead of "timestamp" is stuck with that timezone. Not sure what it's using right now, but it's highly unlikely that it will change, so you'll have to make the query tweak in your end - you should be able to hardcode it.